# do not understand the query string parse with function and parameter

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, web-development-server

I do not understand such snippet of code. is there any master can help me explain that:
I already search the explanation of `querystring.parse(str, [sep], [eq], [options])`. However, I do not understand why there is a "`= function (str){}`" after it. thanks
Here is the code:

```js
(function () 
 {
    'use strict';
    var queryString = {};
 
    queryString.parse = function (str) //do not know why there is a function assigned here
 {
        if (typeof str !== 'string') 
      {
            return {};
        }

        str = str.trim().replace(/^\?/, '');

        if (!str) {
            return {};
        }
  }
});
```

Comment: In JS Function is a full-blown Object.

Comment: You've got a function expression (the outermost part of your code) which isn't assigned anything or called. If it *was* called, then the `queryString` object would be created, have the `parse` method added, and then the entire thing would drop out of scope without being used. So the entire thing does nothing. So I've no idea why *any* of it exists.

Answer (score 1):

It's just saying that it is a function and it will run the code inside the curly brackets when called.
In this case `queryString` is not the node module, since it was not required and assignet to that value(like one would with `const querystring = require('querystring')`), instead it is just an empty object (as you can see in `var queryString = {}`)

Comment: You explained very well. I now understand. Thank you so much and appreciate it.